# How do I limit access to a DevExpress tab ribbon?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-7

I have a project in which I will restrict access to a certain DevExpress tab ribbon based on the user's privileges. In particular, `dxRibbon1tab1` should only be accessible to admin users. I wrote the following code, but it doesn't with property visible

```
procedure Tfmenu.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (level) = 'admin' then
  begin
    dxRibbon1tab1.visible := True;
    fmainform.Caption:= 'this is form for admin';
  end
  else
  begin
    dxRibbon1tab1.visible:= False;
    fmenu.Caption:='this is a form for user'; 
  end;        
end;
```

How do I keep non-admin users from using this special tab ribbon?

Comment: BTW: Inside methods of the form class simply use `Caption` instead of `Form1.Caption`.

Comment: What is `level` and where/how is it set?  Did you attempt to debug?  Put a breakpoint on `if (level)...` and see what the value of `level` is.  Is it `admin`?

Comment: I just tried it: "Doesn't work" means "doesn't compile" because there is no `Enabled` property. With a quick look I didn't see some other way to disable a ribbon tab but you can hide it using `Visible`.

Comment: Contact the component vendor

Comment: i mean it is code cannot running in my project

Comment: level is a field in database to between user and admin

Comment: @user3451766: Your code doesn't even compile. Therefore it cannot run, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use TdxRibbonTab.Visible to show/hide tabs.

Another option would be contextual tabs (search for "Ribbon Contextual Tab" in DevExpress help).

A 3rd option would be use the TdxBar.Visible property to show/hide parts of a tab.

To learn about DevExpress Bar Suite also have a look at their demos

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure that you enable / disable the actions that are associated with the buttons on the tab. Even though the tab may be invisible, shortcut keys that are assigned to the actions will still work.

Answer (score 0):

You can code like below..

```
 dxRibbon1Tab1.Groups[0].ToolBar.Visible:=false;
```